# Можно ли сделать так чтобы модуль os открывал файл зная только его название?

Tags: ос

Чтобы открыть какой либо файл модулю os нужно указать полный путь файла по типу C://Da.exe но если этот файл лежит в другом пути он его не откроет, можно ли сделать так чтобы os находил файл только по названию

Comment: Ну можно... вот только если по файловой системе раскидано несколько файлов с таким именем, получишь лотерею.

Comment: PATH — это системная переменная, содержащая список директорий, в которых ОС будет искать исполняемый файл при вызове команды из консоли.